# On one of variables changes value

Tags: qt, qml

I have for example:

```
property var taskType: null
property var taskKind: null
```

so when I want to run some script each time one of those varibales cahnges, I would do something like:

```
onTaskTypeChanged: { bla() }
onTaskKindChanged: { bla() }
```

so as you can see, i need to run the same function when one of those changes... however happens that both of them changes at the same time, so I wish to run the scrip only once... so something like:

```
if (taskTypeChaned OR taskKindChanged) { bla() }
```

but that is obvously not correct...

so is there any way for qml to evalute in one of those two variables changes and then run the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Qt.callLater`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#callLater-method) function:

```
onTaskTypeChanged: Qt.callLater(bla)
onTaskKindChanged: Qt.callLater(bla)
```